# Looking for best fit solution for a email recipients' suggestion

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, recommendation-engine

I have a dataset that contains email interaction between a large user group. I mean which user sends en email to other users. The most significant column of that data is **sender_id, receiver_id, time** etc. I want to come up with a solution for suggesting **receiver_id** using machine learning (I solved it using graph theory concepts), now want to apply a machine learning solution here, as a learning process.

I need some help and ideas for this particular problem,

1. what should be a machine learning approach to suggest multiple receiver id (max 5 to 10 users) based on the previous interactions?
2. Also, how to describe this problem, either a regression one or a classification one? I'm confused!
3. As per my understanding this problem closely related to *email recipients' recommendation*, please share some good papers on that issue. Actually, I'm not sure how to apply, Collaborative filtering on that problem as I have no access to the email body, there is no possibility to apply content-based approaches. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your training set. If you have sufficient number of features for "receiving" output and sufficient number of data then you may use multi-classification. But since I assume that there are too much receiver, clustering would be a better option. You can create clusters from your features and recommend the emails to the users that are in the same cluster. For example, [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266475973_Clustering-Based_Recommender_System_Using_Principles_of_Voting_Theory) uses that approach.